# Как создать класс словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Есть ли возможность к примеру создать класс `Аdict`, который бы работал, как словарь?
т.е. к примеру `Adict[5] = 'test'`
Сделать класс, экземпляры, которого будут словарями, сложности не составляет. Надо всего лишь наследоваться от класса `dict`. И я подумал, что аналогично можно создать и метакласс, экземпляры, которого будучи классами, тоже работали бы схожим образом, но я не понимаю от чего надо наследоваться и какие методы следует переопределять. Надо ли наследоваться от `dict` или метаклассы могут наследоваться только от `type`?
Я хоть немного двигаюсь в правильном направлении здесь?:

```
class ADictMeta(dict):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, args, kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__dict__[item]


class Adict(metaclass=ADictMeta):
    pass
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метакласс должен быть потомком типа `type`, по крайней мере, если вы хотите чтобы класс, созданный с таким метаклассом являлся именно классом, а не просто словарем.

А наследоваться от `dict` вообще не обязательно, если в качестве хранилища вы используете внутренний словарь класса.

```
class ADictMeta(type):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        setattr(self, key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

class Adict(metaclass=ADictMeta):
    pass
```

```
Adict['key'] = 'value'
print(Adict.key) # value
```

Если же нужно отдельное хранилище, то все равно лучше не наследоваться от `dict`, вряд ли множественное наследование здесь пройдет успешно. Для того, чтобы другие объекты воспринимали его как изменяемый словарь, достаточно чтобы он реализовал методы базового класса `MutableMapping`

```
class ADictMeta(type):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mydict = {}

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.mydict[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.mydict[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.mydict[key]

    def clear(self):
        self.mydict.clear()

    def pop(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.mydict.pop(*args, **kwargs)

    def popitem(self):
        return self.mydict.popitem()

    def setdefault(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.mydict.setdefault(*args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mydict.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.mydict

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.mydict.get(*args, **kwargs)

    def items(self):
        return self.mydict.items()

    def keys(self):
        return self.mydict.keys()

    def values(self):
        return self.mydict.values()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.mydict)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.mydict)

class Adict(metaclass=ADictMeta):
    pass
```

```
Adict['key'] = 'value'
print(dict(Adict)) # {'key': 'value'}
print({**Adict, 'key2': 'value2'}) # {'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'}
```